# textbox is being filled but datepicker is not via mvvm binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datepicker, propertychanged

I have a textbox with a date in it and I want to convert it to a datepicker for twoway binding. But unfortunately the datepicker doesn't show the date.

```
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
                         Grid.Column="4"
                         IsReadOnly="False"
                         Text="{Binding Path=BirthDate,
                                        Mode=OneWay,
                                        StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy'}" />
```

The following code does not work, the selecteddate shows empty... (while there is a value in it)

```
                <DatePicker Grid.Row="1"
                           Grid.Column="4" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" SelectedDate="{Binding BirthDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ></DatePicker>
```

In another location in the application I also have a datepicker that Does work:

```
            <DatePicker x:Name="DatePicker" 
                    Grid.Row="3"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    FirstDayOfWeek="Monday"
                    SelectedDate="{Binding Parameter.PAR_Date,
                                           Mode=TwoWay}"  />
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong, it seems very simple.

I can just type a date in the datepicker and this works... so very strange... any ideas would be welcome...

EDIT:

Got a step closer by using snoop and looking in to the binding on the datepicker and it seems to have an error, I seem to have a different expected type:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to perform 'two-way' conversions between types 'EVD.Framework.NullableDateTime' and 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]'. Consider using Converter property of Binding. BindingExpression:Path=Birthdate; DataItem='SomeModel' (HashCode=31671132); target element is 'DatePicker' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectedDate' (type 'Nullable`1')
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='04/10/1929' BindingExpression:Path=Birthdate; DataItem='SomeModel' (HashCode=31671132); target element is 'DatePicker' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectedDate' (type 'Nullable`1')
```

EDIT 2:

That was it, in the code the datetime was a NullableDateTime. Thanks to everyone pitching in ideas, especially Viv. Votes up for everyone with a decent suggestion :-)

Comment: Can you show more code? For example where and how you set the value for `BirthDate`?

Comment: works fine for me. Are you sure you're `DatePicker.DataContext` is right and it's actually able to find the property? You can check it with [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) at runtime to make sure the DataContext is right and the `SelectedDate` Binding is valid on the `DatePicker`.

Comment: Have you checked for binding errors in the immediate window?

Comment: Hey Viv, I got a step closer to the problem by using Snoop. Thanks for that Tip. See my edits .

Answer (score 2):

This article does a good job explaining StringFormat:
http://elegantcode.com/2009/04/07/wpf-stringformat-in-xaml-with-the-stringformat-attribute/

You need to remember to use **{0}** when formatting.